# How to convert group of SQL records to the single row basing on max and min values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, grouping

We are storing the employee statuses history in the SQL Server table. There are Employee ID (Foreign Key), Start & End Date, and Employee Status columns. NULL in the End date column means that that status is active now. An employee can be active, can be terminated, and then become active again.

Because of the bug in the client app, each time an employee profile is updated, it generates the new record to the table, where the start date is the end date of the previous record (see records # 1,2,3). E.g., Employee #1 was active from 1 of Jan to the 1 of April, then they were terminated for three months and rehired again.

| Record ID | Employee ID | Start Date | End Date | Employee Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | Active |
| 2 | 1 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-03-01 | Active |
| 3 | 1 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-04-01 | Active |
| 4 | 1 | 2019-04-01 | 2019-07-01 | Terminated |
| 5 | 1 | 2019-07-01 | NULL | Active |
| 6 | 2 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | Active |
| 7 | 2 | 2019-01-01 | NULL | Active |
| 8 | 3 | 2019-01-01 | NULL | Active |

We can't fix UI right now, so we are planning to run the script quite often.
I am able to write the script with cursor/cycle in the imperative style, but I don't think the performance will be good as we have a large number of Employee Status records (for the first run) and a lot of employees in general.

I want a declarative  script that will replace rows #1, 2, 3 with a single row like:

| Record ID | Employee ID | Start Date | End Date | Employee Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-04-01 | Active |

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would suggest using `lag()` and a cumulative sum to identify the groups:

```
select min(recordid) as recordid, employeeid, status, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_enddate = startdate then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by employeeid order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(enddate) over (partition by employeeid, status order by startdate) as prev_enddate
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by employeeid, status, grp;
```

Basically, this peeks at the previous row for the same employee and status.  If does not adjoins the current row, then the current row starts a new group.